# Sobreescribir, reutilizar Messages (Handler)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, hilos

Al ejecutar el siguiente código:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"BusyWait"})
@Override
public void run() {
    Bundle datos = new Bundle();
    Message msg = new Message();

    for(Integer i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        try {
            datos.putString("mensaje", i.toString());
            msg.setData(datos);

            handler.sendMessage(msg);
            Thread.sleep(2000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

después de la primera iteración básicamente me sale este error:

> *java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>
> target=com.runner.handler.MainActivityHandler$MyHandler
> This message is already in use.*

Lo cual es bastante lógico.

---

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de que se pueda llamar al setData de un mismo objeto Message mas de una vez **¿Es posible reutilizar un mismo objeto Message, pero con diferente mensaje, valga la redundancia?**

Comment: por qué no simplemente creas una instancia de `Message` en cada iteración?

Comment: Es lo que hago actualmente, pero quería saber si existía otra forma que no implicará crear tantos objetos Message @Chochos